# When setting up a virtual environment in PyCharm, I get the error: Error: [WinError 2] The system can't find the files

Tags: python, pycharm

When setting up the virtual environment for the first time in PyCharm, I get the following error:

Error: [WinError 2] The system can't find the files.

```
Unable to copy 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python3\\venvlauncher.exe'
Unable to copy 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python3\\venvwlauncher.exe'
Error: [WinError 2] The system can't find the files.
```

I have Python 3.7 installed, but for some reason not those files.

I'm a noob at Python, just trying the first steps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you [set the interpreter to the correct path](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)? Seems like Python3 isn't in those directories.

Comment: No, the Python3-files are in this directory, just not those 2 files.

Comment: But, I found a work-around, instead of setting up a virtual environment, I just set up the Python 3.8 interpreter as the project interpreter in PyCharm. Easy peasy.